# Get Double Nested JSON Response Parse Javascript API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, parse-platform, parse-server

I am calling my Parse Server & pulling data down using the Parse Javascript API into my Angular V1 (is that JS or IO?!) application.  My call function is as follows:

```
$scope.getInventoryItems = function () {

    var query = new Parse.Query("Inventory");
    query.include("product");
    query.include("retailer");
    query.find({

        success: function (results) {

            $scope.inventoryItems = [];

            for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

                var p = results[i].get("product");
                var r = results[i].get("retailer");

                var inventoryItem = {

                    objectId: results[i].id,
                    productObjectId: p.id,
                    barcode: p.get("barcode"),
                    productName: p.get("name"),
                    imageUrl: p.get("image"),
                    Qty: results[i].get("QTY"),
                    newQty: results[i].get("QTY"),
                    shoppingQty: 1,
                    retailerImage: r.get.Logo("url"),
                    retailerName: r.get("Name")
                }
                console.log(inventoryItem);
                $scope.inventoryItems[$scope.inventoryItems.length] = inventoryItem;

            }

            $scope.$apply();

        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log("Query Error: " + error.message);
        }
    })
}
```

Heres the JSON server response:

```
{
    "results": [{
        "objectId": "Fo02snRmlP",
        "product": {
            "objectId": "eCA7BwB7kF",
            "barcode": 54775912,
            "name": "Extra Peppermint Gum 5 Pack",
            "image": "[image url removed]",
            "createdAt": "2017-11-22T01:28:16.605Z",
            "updatedAt": "2017-11-22T01:28:16.605Z",
            "__type": "Object",
            "className": "Products"
        },
        "QTY": 4,
        "createdAt": "2017-11-22T01:28:16.859Z",
        "updatedAt": "2017-11-22T01:28:16.859Z",
        "ACL": {
            "NV6ubzeAHL": {
                "read": true,
                "write": true
            }
"retailer": {
            "objectId": "u2qNoKDAWV",
            "Name": "My Supermarket",
            "createdAt": "2017-09-20T17:16:48.151Z",
            "updatedAt": "2017-11-13T19:40:26.371Z",
            "Logo": {
                "__type": "File",
                "name": "c600325c63f7fb252b36c08c8c6168ab_supermarket_logo_full.svg",
                "url": "https://my-api.herokuapp.com//files/my-api/c600325c63f7fb252b36c08c8c6168ab_supermarket_logo_full.svg"
            },
            "shortName": "supermarket",
            "__type": "Object",
            "className": "Retailers"
        },
        }
    }, {
```

Everything is successful, except for the logo URL which I am trying to collect using `retailerImage: r.get.Logo("url")`.  How would I get this double nested item?

Thanks

Comment: r.get:ACL.Logo('url')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Logo` is another property of `retailer`, right? Looks like you just need to use `r.get('Logo').url()`

Here's the [parse docs example](http://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#retrieving-file-contents):

```
var profilePhoto = profile.get("photoFile");
$("profileImg")[0].src = profilePhoto.url();
```

Comment: Thats it. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to assist! :D